# How can I disable SNI for a request in node?

Tags: node.js

I am using https.request and I would like to completely disable SNI(Server Name Indication) for requests. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out a way to do it by creating a custom `.createConnection` function

```
var tls=require("tls")
var https=require("https")

var options={
    host:"example.com",
    port:443,
    path:"/"
}
var agentOptions = {
    rejectUnauthorized: true //this option disables certificate verification when it is false, you may need to disable it to connect to a server without having SNI enabled
}
var agent = new https.Agent(agentOptions)
agent.createConnection=function(options,callback){
    options.servername=undefined //setting servername to undefined disables SNI 
    return socket=tls.connect(options,callback)     
}
options.agent=agent
request=https.request(options,function(response){

    response.on("data",function(data){
        console.log(data.toString())
    })

})
request.end()
```